# How would I make a variable update from a row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I writing a program with a `JTable`

```
// I'm not going to write all the beginning stuff
 DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
 JTable t = new JTable(model);
 Object[] 1 = {x, y, z};
 model.addRow(1);
 String s = 1
```

I was wondering how would I make it so if someone were to edit while the program was running how would I make so up date; so say `y = 6` and then someone changed it to `8` how would I make s update to `8` too?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that a "user was to edit the table", not the program....?

Comment: Start by taking a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) for details about how to make a `JTable` editable...

Comment: to MadProgrammer yes I did mean that

Comment: You need to use `@{username}` to address a comment back to a given user ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) for details about how to make a table editable.

There are a number of conditions that need to be meet...

1. `TableModel#isCellEdtiable` must return `true` for the specified column
2. The `TableCellEditor#isCellEditable` must return `true` for the specified trigger event

That will allow the cell to be edited...

In order to update the data:

1. `TableModel#setValueAt` method must be capable of receiving the value from the editor and applying to the underlying data and then trigger the `tableCellUpdated` event notification

Now, the good news is, for the most part, this is all setup by default by the `JTable` and `DefaultTabelModel`...

Try double clicking on the given cell, it should enter edit mode, you should be able to change it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the value should be applied back to the data within the `TableModel`

Now, if you're interested in being notified when the `TableModel` is changed, you will need to register a `TableModelListener` with the `TableModel`.